# How to add prefix to array values?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of values to which I want to add some prefix:

```
var arr = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "some.jpg"];
```

Adding the prefix `images/` should result in this:

```
newArr = ["images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg", "images/some.jpg"];
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map` is a great tool for this kind of things:

```
arr.map(function(el) { 
  return 'images/' + el; 
})
```

In ES2015+:

```
arr.map(el => 'images/' + el)
```

Answer (score 21):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const newArr = arr.map(i => 'images/' + i)
```

Same thing but without using [ES6](http://es6-features.org/) syntax:

```
var arr = arr.map(function (i){
    return 'images/' + i;
})
```

Answer (score 6):

For browser compatibility and without loop:

```
var pre = 'images/';
var arr = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', 'some.jpg'];
var newArr = (pre + arr.join(';' + pre)).split(';');
```

Comment: What if the contents of the file name contains ";", as in "me;mycat.jpg"

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this with a simple loop:

```
var arr = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","some.jpg"],
    newArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    newArr[i] = 'images/' + arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery library

```
var newArr = jQuery.map( arr, function( n, i ) {
  return ( "images/"+n );
});
```

Comment: Who said anything about jQuery?

Comment: I love how the jQuery version is longer than the native version - and slower

Comment: Native version is not work in IE 8. The question can be opened from the different parties, native approach has been proposed in other answers.

Comment: There are other substitutes for `Array.map()` that don't involve including an entire library. [Johnroe Paulo Cañamaque's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26116174/1612146) for example.