# JavaScript: Array of numbers to date-time string format

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, datetime

I have an array of number

```
var year = [1999,2000,2001,2002,2003];
```

and I need to convert to date-time formar

```
var yearConvert =["1999-00-00","2000-00-00","2001-00-00","20002-00-00","2003-00-00"];
```

I only have year which is an integer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding text to beginning of each array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498409/adding-text-to-beginning-of-each-array-element) and [How to add a dot before each item in this list of array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048043) and [How to add text to end of each array element using map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705444) and [How to add prefix to array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115971) and [Add a prefix to all the element of an array of strings using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51784163)

Comment: "1999-00-00" is not a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and concat ***`-00-00`*** on each element

```js
var year = [1999,2000,2001,2002,2003];

let op = year.map(e => e+'-00-00')

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do it. But the returned array will have the values as string not as `Date` object.

```js
const year = [1999,2000,2001,2002,2003];
const dateString = year.map((ele) => `${ele}-00-00`);
console.log(dateString);

//Convert this array to Date Objects using Date constructor Date(year, monthIndex, day) month starts from '0'

const date = dateString.map((str) => { 
  const data = str.split('-');
  return new Date(data[0], data[1], data[2]+1);
});

console.log(date)

//To verify parse to date strings

const dateParsed = date.map((date) => date.toDateString());
console.log(dateParsed);
```